# how to index a value in t a list which is in a list

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have the following list:

```
commands = [['move', '3', '4'], ['move', '4', '5'], ['move', '5', '6']]
```

I want to compare the first value in each list (the move's) to see if they are the same, I know for a normal list you would use list_name[index], but not sure how to do it for this as there is a list inside a list?

any idea? x

Comment: `commands[index][0]`

Comment: If `list_name[index]` is another list, why not `list_name[index][index_again]`?

Comment: list_name[index][index2]

Comment: You should look for and follow a tutorial on [two-dimensional lists](https://www.google.com/search?q=2d+list+python). Please take the [tour], and read [ask] and [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic). 
[Asking on Stack Overflow is not a substitute for doing your own research.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)

Comment: And to see if they're all the same you'd do `all(c[0] == commands[0][0] for c in commands)`.

Comment: @Samwise you said "And to see if they're all the same you'd do all(c[0] == commands[0][0] for c in commands". what is the c? thanks

Comment: `for c in commands` loops over everything in `commands`, assigning each element to the value `c`.

Comment: @Samwise okay thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In general:

```
list_of_lists[index1][index2]
```

To get a list of first items of each sublist:

```
[cmd[0] for cmd in commands]
```

To check if they're all the same:

```
len(set(cmds[0] for cmds in commands)) == 1
```

You can easily adjust this approach to your specific use case.